# Cannot use interpreters in Zeppelin

Tags: r, apache-spark

I just start using Zeppelin with Scala and R. I have got a problem with interpreters. I download zeppelin from https://zeppelin.apache.org/download.html. I use `zeppelin-0.6.1-bin-all.tgz`.

After setting up everything, I use Firefox to use Zeppelin by visiting http://localhost:8082. I also did Interpreter binding by clicking to Bind/Unbind interpreter and then click save button. However, when I use R or Spark, I have got an information:

> Prefix not found.

When I try spark.r, I have got an information:

> spark.r interpreter not found.

Image:

[image]

Comment: Mostly likely your spark interpreter could not start properly. R does not bundled by default. I just tested, 0.6.1 works on my macbook. There should be some hint in logs file zeppelin-interpreter-spark-*.log.

Comment: Thanks, I will double check. I do this in ubuntu in vmware. I use the latest R, spark, scala and zeppelin. I read this from somewhere else. Some people says this probably is a bug of zeppelin.

Comment: Check this file in zeppelin directory `./interpreter/spark/zeppelin-zrinterpreter_2.11-0.6.1.jar`. Does it exist? Could you remove `./conf/interpreter.json` and restart zeppelin?

Comment: thanks. I will try it.